# Base table or view not found while creating magento install script

Tags: sql, magento

Here are all my files.

app/code/local/Vlabs/Productquery/sql/productquery_setup/resource-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
  $installer = $this;
  $installer->startSetup();

 $installer->run("
  -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('Vlabs_queryBox')};
    CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('Vlabs_queryBox')} (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default,
      `email`  varchar(255),
      `query`  varchar(255),
      `product_name` varchar(255),
      `sku` varchar(255),
      `answer` varchar(255),
      `status` varchar(255),
      `date` date NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
  ");

  $installer->endSetup();
```

app/code/local/Vlabs/Productquery/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vlabs_Productquery>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Vlabs_Productquery>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <productquery>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Vlabs_Productquery</module>
                    <frontName>productquery</frontName>
                </args>
            </productquery>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <productquery module="Vlabs_Productquery">
                    <file>productquery.xml</file>
                </productquery>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <productquery>
                <class>Vlabs_Productquery_Block</class>
            </productquery>
        </blocks>

        <models>
            <productquery>
                <class>Vlabs_Productquery_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>productquery_Resource</resourceModel>
            </productquery>
            <productquery_Resource>
                <class>Vlabs_Productquery_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <querybox>
                        <table>Vlabs_queryBox</table>
                    </querybox>
                </entities>
            </productquery_Resource>
        </models>
         <helpers>
          <productquery>
            <class>Vlabs_Productquery_Helper</class>
          </productquery>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <form_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Vlabs_Productquery</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </form_setup>
            <form_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </form_write>
            <form_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </form_read>
        </resources>
        <template>
        <email>
            <vlabs_query_email_template translate="label">
                <label>Recurring order email</label>
                <file>vlabs_querybox_email.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </vlabs_query_email_template>
        </email>
    </template>   
    </global>

     <!-- <default>
        <productquery>
            <settings>
                <enable>1</enable>              
            </settings>
        </productquery>
    </default> -->

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Vlabs_Productquery before="Mage_Adminhtml">Vlabs_Productquery_Adminhtml</Vlabs_Productquery>
                    </modules>
                    <frontname>productquery</frontname>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin> 
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <productquery>
                    <file>productquery.xml</file>
                </productquery>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
</config>
```

app/code/local/Vlabs/Productquery/Model/Resource/Querybox/Setup.php

```
<?php 
class Vlabs_Productquery_Model_Resource_Querybox_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup {
}
```

**Error**

```
a:5:{i:0;s:179:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento_mirror_new.Vlabs_queryBox' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `Vlabs_queryBox` AS `main_table`";i:1;s:5763:"#0 /var/www/html/magento-mirror-new/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

I am working on making an extension.. But table is not created in database. But query is working when run this query direct in mysql. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have installed your module and later you changed the database name.

Go to core_resource table and try to delete this entry "form_setup". Then clear cache and try again. I hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you Jickson Johnson Koottala. I have deleted "form_setup" table. and then clear cached. But it is not working still now.

Comment: @Mayuri noticed one thing with the setup folder name. I think it should be "form_setup" instead of "productquery_setup". Could you please try this